# PHP File upload css issue

Tags: php, html, css

I have this problem when I upload a file the filename and filesize that supposed too be displayed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbUgo.jpg are now displayed at the top of my webpage here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/748Tu.jpg.

I dont have a clue of how this is happening and havent found anything css related to the input file type so i can reposition the text. None of my css is repositioning `<lu>` or `<li>` tags where the text gets placed in.

here is de code from my form **[EDIT] I updated this code with the rest of the file (body only)**:

```
<body onLoad="javascript:LoadPage();" onblur="SetCaching(2);" onfocus="SetCaching(3);">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>      
    <div id="container">
        <table>             
            <tr>
                <td>                        
                    <div id="chatcontent" style="background-image:url('assets/img/main.png'); height: 400px; width:550px;">
                    //filename and filesize get outputted here
                    </div>                      
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="chatlogo">
                        <img src="assets/img/reclame.png" alt="reclame" id="reclame"/>                      
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="messagearea">
                        <form role="form" id="fMain" name="fMain" onSubmit="SetCaching(3); return Submit();">
                            <div id="messageControls" >                             
                                <div style="width: 420px;float: left;">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="textmessage" name="textmessage" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo $chat_textbox; ?>" onClick="if(this.value == 'Type hier...') this.value='';" onkeypress="javascript:SetCaching(1);" onblur="javascript:SetCaching(3)"/>
                                </div>      
                                <div style="float: right;">
                                    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="<?php echo $chat_chatsend; ?>" autocomplete="off" style="width:115px;" onClick="javascript:SendChat();"/>
                                </div>  
                                <br/><br/>
                                <div>
                                    <p style="font-size: 14px;" id="lblStatus" name="lblStatus">
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ivolnl" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>                            
                    <div id="upload">
                        <form id="fupload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">                             
                            <input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="uplLink" value="Bestand uploaden" autocomplete="off" style="width:115px; min-width: 151px;" onclick="$('#upl').trigger('click');" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000" />
                            <input type="file" name="upl" id="upl"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </td>               
            </tr>           
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#uplLink{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#upl{    
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

php file upload.php:

```
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'psd', 'ai', 'pdf');
if($_FILES["upl"]["size"] < 10000000) {
    if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $cookie = $_COOKIE["ChatID"];
        $path = "uploads/" . $cookie;   

        if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
            exit;
        }

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $name = $_FILES['upl']['name'];
        $actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $original_name = $actual_name;
        $name_extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $i = 1;
        while(file_exists($path."/".$actual_name.".".$name_extension))
        {           
            $actual_name = (string)$original_name."_".$i;
            $name = $actual_name.".".$name_extension;
            $i++;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $path."/".$name)){
            exit;
        }
    }
}
exit;
```

From what i am seeing is that is somehow is getting randomly placed in the first `<lu>` tag. I am working on this on a localhost XAMPP server.

Comment: Since you don't show ANY of the code that outputs this mispositioned data into your document, we can't really help you.

Comment: Maybe upload.php needs a `<?php` at the start....

Comment: @MarcB i am not outputting any data via code. this is purely done by doing this: 1. click on button. 2. select picture, click open. 3. data gets put their

Comment: seems it's behavior of some javascript uploader stuff. Turn off javascript in browser and check as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, so i found the problem, i was including a script in the head that uses jquery.fileupload to upload the file. In there it was specified to output the data were i didnt want it to be, so i changed it. Thanks for all the comments, especially @Deadooshka